# spring:url not working

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a tag that fails to load the view name. My servlet context is test. I define the url:

```
<spring:url var="editContactUrl" value="/next" />
```

And below is the tag:

```
 <a href="${editContactUrl}">Try Again</a>
```

What I get is just the servlet context with the value ("/next") in the spring:url ignored, as below:

```
http://localhost:8080/test
```

Could someone enlighten me? Thanks. Oh yeah, I also tried specifying context in the spring:url and same result.

Edit: What I'm trying to do is simply route the reference to the controller which is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "/next", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String next(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,   DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "next";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me why are you using

```
@RequestMapping("/*")
```

on you're controller class.
At class level you should define the base path. An at method level you should refine more specific mappings.
However try instead:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```

Furthermore you can try to use:

```
<c:url var="editContactUrl" value="/next"/>
```

in place of:

```
<spring:url var="editContactUrl" value="/next"/>
```

It should provide similar functionalities.

Comment: I am getting same issue. seems spring:url is not working in href and i used c:url (jstl) and it worked, Question is WHY?